# Facing 404 while accessing a php file

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

After doing some changes to my plugin [amtyThumb](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/amtythumb/), I realized that there is some problem to access imgsize.php. But i dint change anything in imgsize.php.

If i put this script into some other folder other than plugin folder on my site, then everything is working fine. I am keeping file permission 644 on both places. Folder permission is 755 on both places. It is working fine if i run it locally on my PC.

I had checked .htaccess for hotlinking. But it is not enable.

visit [article-stack](http://article-stack.com) to view the problem. If you open page in IE or chrome, you can see broken image sign or cross sign in place of images which should be appear just before the post title in sidebar.

In addition, I am using previous version of this plugin on my one of the sites where it is working fine. visit [thinkzarahatke](http://thinkzarahatke.com/thinks). All images in footer bar and sidebar, are being displayed through amtyThumb 1.0.

**For debugging** : I added some code to write to a text file (just to check). But even that code is not getting executed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time i found the silly mistake i did. I actually was calling script resides in "amtyThumb" but the actual plugin url was having "amtythumb".